# windows cmd(clink) doskey, how to copy the current directory to clipboard, prepended by "cd"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos, doskey

It is ok to do this in the command line:

```
C:\Users\ken.chen>echo|set /p=cd %cd%|clip

C:\Users\ken.chen>cd C:\Users\ken.chen

C:\Users\ken.chen\nuts\notes>echo|set /p=cd %cd%|clip

C:\Users\ken.chen\nuts\notes>cd C:\Users\ken.chen\nuts\notes
```

but the variabe %cd% is always my home directory if I add a doskey cc to my initialization batch file:

```
doskey cc=echo^|set /p=cd %cd%^|clip


C:\Users\ken.chen\nuts\notes>cc

C:\Users\ken.chen\nuts\notes>cd C:\Users\ken.chen
```

how to fix it? or do I need to write it in a separate batch file?

Comment: I end up adding a cc.bat file containing two lines: @echo off<br/>echo|set /p dummyName=cd %cd%|clip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cd` variable always "contains" the same directory because it was evaluated once, when the macro was created, and at that point the home directory was current.

If you escape the `%` characters, however, the variable will be evaluated at every invocation of `cc`:

```
doskey cc=echo^|set /p=cd ^%cd^%^|clip
```

But that method of escaping the `%` would work only in the command line. To escape them in a batch file, use a different method:

```
doskey cc=echo^|set /p=cd %%cd%%^|clip
```

Comment: your answer gave me a hint, but to escape the %, i tested that ^ not works in my cmd.exe initialization .bat file, % do works.

Comment: You are right, I indeed tested this directly in the command line rather than in a batch file (missed the relevant detail in your question). I actually tried `%%` at first but it didn't work properly (in the command line). Well, the variable did evaluate at every invocation of `cc` but there were also `%`s around the path. I realise that this is not an issue when you use escape the percents with `%%` in a batch file, well done figuring that out!

Comment: @metaphy: Thank you for accepting my answer. I've updated it to match your question more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply use the below?

```
echo.cd "%cd%" | clip
```

alternate methods-

If your path does not contain any space, you could do it with the one liner -

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('dir ^|findstr /i /c:"directory of"') do (echo.cd "%%i"| clip)
```

If it contains any space(s) -

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir ^| findstr /i /c:"Directory of"') do set mypath=%%i
set mypath=%mypath: Directory of =%
echo.cd "%mypath%"| clip
```

Cheers, G